# MySQL select all rows having latest value per id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I have table that looks like this:

```
| id | user | data |
--------------------
| 1  |  11  | aaa1 |
| 2  |  11  | aaa2 |
| 3  |  11  | aaa3 |
| 4  |  22  | aaa4 |
| 5  |  33  | aaa5 |
| 6  |  33  | aaa6 |
| 7  |  44  | aaa7 |
```

I want to select all rows, with all data, and I want to add data with `max id` per `user`, that should look like this:

```
| id | user | data | f_id | f_data |
------------------------------------
| 1  |  11  | aaa1 |   3  |  aaa3  |
| 2  |  11  | aaa2 |   3  |  aaa3  |
| 3  |  11  | aaa3 |   3  |  aaa3  |
| 4  |  22  | aaa4 |   4  |  aaa4  |
| 5  |  33  | aaa5 |   6  |  aaa6  |
| 6  |  33  | aaa6 |   6  |  aaa6  |
| 7  |  44  | aaa7 |   7  |  aaa7  |
```

this is my attempt of query:

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.id AS f_id, t2.data AS f_data
        FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table1 t2
             ON t1.user=(SELECT MAX(t2.id)
                         FROM table1 t2
                         WHERE t2.user = t1.user )
```

**Update:**
All the answers are correct, but when I run the Query on table with 80K+ rows, MySQL needs a lot of time to Execute the query. For my project I will add ajax so user could click on it and php would execute query for one row per click.

Comment: what is wrong with your query?

Comment: I have to say WHY, it does not seem to make a lot of sense to duplicate `data` into `f_data` and create `f_id` like that, as it will be almost guaranteed to get messed up in the future. REVISIT your database design

Comment: it gives `null` in `f_id` and `f_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a24413/6)**

```
SELECT  t1.*, 
        t2.id AS f_id, 
        t2.data AS f_data
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.user = t2.user
 AND t2.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id)
              FROM table1 t3
              WHERE t3.user = t1.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
SELECT  t1.*, t3.id AS f_id, concat(SUBSTRING(t1.data, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(t1.data)-1),t3.id) AS f_data
        FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN (select max(t2.id) as id, t2.user as userid from table1 t2 group by t2.user) t3
        on t3.userid = t1.user
```

Sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a24413/7

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using your logic.  Just a few things need to be fixed up:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2max.id AS f_id, t2max.data AS f_data
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table1 t2max
     ON t1.user = t2max.user AND
        t2max.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id)
                    FROM table1 t2
                    WHERE t2.user = t1.user
                   );
```

The changes are:

- You need a condition between the two tables in the `FROM` clause, for the user.
- The subquery needs to join on the `id` not on the `user`.